# Spring MVC Files org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound

Tags: spring, servlets, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have tried multiple times, but still I am getting these issue, but unable to understand from where this is arising.

> Oct 2, 2013 1:50:37 PM
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
>   WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI
>   [/Demo/greeting.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'demoServlet'

My web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>demoServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
     <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>demoServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>
```

And My servlet-config.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.demo.controller" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" p:prefix="/WEB-INF/content/" p:suffix=".jsp"></bean>
```

My HelloController

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value ="/greeting")
    public String sayHello(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("greeting","Hello World !");
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your controller in `com.demo.controller` package?

Comment: Yes @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: Zama can you post or change your post to show the entire web.xml declaration. I think I know what the problem is, but just want to verify.

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea but this solved my problem!! [Would Like to know the reason for the original problem]

I changed

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
```

to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

and it ran perfectly fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace:

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/greeting")
```

with:

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/greeting.html")
```

Comment: Tried it. But with no success.